# Rails 3 SQL query inside nested resources

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

Say I have a series of nested resources (`Magazine`, `Edition`, and `Ad`) in a Rails application, such that magazines have many editions, which subsequently have many ads.

How can I do a query to produce all ads in all editions of a given magazine, and then order them, for example, by date created?

Ideally, I'd like to produce an array with all the results using a single SQL query, as opposed to doing a query for each edition and then combining the subsequent arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use has_many :through.

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :editions
  has_many :ads, :through => :editions
end

@magazine.ads.order('created_at')
```

**edit** [Read the docs on has_many :through. It's powerful stuff.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)